# Sending json nested within json to a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a Rails 4.1.6 app that functions only as a JSON API,
I have a field "json_data" of type text in a database table called 'cards'.

To my understanding, putting the following code in the Card model...

```
  serialize :json_data, JSON
```

...makes strings stored in this json_data field output properly as JSON (and not a string with escaped quotes) whenever I return the json_data to some requesting client, like when I do

```
json.cards @cards do |card|
    json.id card.id
    json.title card.title
    json.json_data card.json_data
end
```

in a index.json.jbuilder view file, for example.

What is confusing is that I am sending POST and PUT requests of this format to create or update cards:

```
{
  "card":{"title":"card 124","json_data":{"text": "hi"}}
}
```

But json_data is empty each time. A validation for presence of json_data fails!

If, instead, I send the following:

```
{
  "card":{"title":"card 124","json_data":"{\"text\": \"hi\"}"}
}
```

json_data is interpreted correctly, but the data is stored in the database as `json_data: "{\"text\":\"hi\"}"`, with the backslashes, which I think is undesirable.

When looking around the database with `rails console`, shouldn't `json_data` be presented like this?

```
#<Card id: 1, title: "Card 1", json_data: {"text"=>"Lorem ipsum figaro ci yei."}, beacon_owner_id: 1, template_id: 1, created_at: "2015-03-04 19:56:36", updated_at: "2015-03-04 19:56:36">, #<Card id: 2, title: "Card 2", json_data: {"text"=>"Pre va ipsum figaro ci yei.", "image_link"=>"http://i.imgur.com/sNRv0Jq.png"}, beacon_owner_id: 1, template_id: 2, created_at: "2015-03-04 19:56:36", updated_at: "2015-03-04 19:56:36">
```

And not like this?

```
#<Card id: 4, title: "new card", json_data: "{\"text\": \"hi\"}", beacon_owner_id: 1, template_id: 1, created_at: "2015-03-23 02:51:33", updated_at: "2015-03-23 02:51:33">
```

What is the best way to accept POST/PUT requests where parameters involve JSON for a specific text column? Does it have to be an escaped string (because as described above, if it's directly just more nested JSON, then Rails' validation for the presence of the field fails)?

==EDIT==
Added the controller:

```
class API::V1::CardsController < API::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
  before_action :set_card, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    respond_with(@card)
  end

  def index
    @cards = current_beacon_owner.cards
    respond_with(@cards)
  end

  def create
    @card = Card.new(card_params)
    @card.beacon_owner_id = current_beacon_owner.id
    @card.save
    respond_with(@card)
  end

  def update
    @card.update(card_params)
    respond_with(@card)
  end

  def destroy
    @card.destroy
    respond_with(@card)
  end

  private
    def set_card
      @card = Card.find(params[:id])
    end

    def card_params
      puts '-----------------------------------------'
      puts "params: #{params}"
      puts '-----------------------------------------'
      params.require(:card).permit(:title, :json_data, :template_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The knowledge I was missing was about Rails' strong parameters - we're supposed to whitelist nested parameters: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

My controller's card_params was not allowing the nested parameters, hence the validates-presence-of validation failing. Fixing this lets me store data in the database without all the escaping, which is the right way.

Side note: another solution, if using Rails 4.x and postgres, is to use the :json column type for the field.